# psql empty database before restore

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to restore a database of postgreSQL, but before do it i need to empty the restore target database.

Is there an option of psql to do it ?

Now i use a command line as the following :

```
psql -U postgres db_test < testdb.sql
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two options here - if your backup is plain text then you add the -c option to pg_dump - ie

`pg_dump -c mydb > mydb.sql`

Otherwise if your using -Fc or -Ft on pg_dump then you use the -c flag on pg_restore

`pg_dump -Ft -b mydb > db.tar`

`pg_restore -c -d newdb db.tar`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about restoring from a `pg_dump` backup the answer is "it depends on how the backup was made", but typically yes: You must empty the database before restoring the backup.

The fastest way to empty out a database in Postgres is to drop and re-create the database (you'll probably need superuser privileges for that), otherwise you have to manually drop each table and any stored procedures you may have (`CASCADE` is your friend here).

Comment: is there a way of do a backup with pg_dump that when i restore it, first erase the destination db and then restore the data ?

Thanks

Comment: I use `--clean` and `--if-exists` arguments on *both* `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` which works really well, but I'm also using the `--format=c` (custom) output format rather than a dump SQL statements. I'm also using PostgreSQL 12 and this question/answer is a bit older than that!